# Upgrading process terminated! How to fix it?

Tags: update-manager

I yesterday started upgrade from Ubuntu 11.10 to Ubuntu 12.04 and i terminated it just when it was installing packages (don't ask me why). Today when i tried to repeat procedure when i turned on update manager it pop out a warning box which says "Not all upgrades can be installed" and has some buttons on it. One of those is "Partial upgrade", and when i click it it starts some window which says "Can not upgrade, an upgrade from 'precise' do 'oneiric' is not supported with this tool" (before that it asks me for my password)  . How can i now upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04 without reinstalling entire Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 3):

Run `sudo apt-get -f install` first. After that, try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.